# awk's $1 conflicts with $1 in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I am writting a shell script which includes a couple of awk lines

the awk line looks like:

```
cat input.csv | awk -F, '$1~/$1/ {print "is good"}'
```

the first `$1` is the first column of the input csv, the second `$1` is supposed to be the first command line input of this shell script

I tried to put a `\` in front of the second `$`, but it seems to be not working.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 5):

```
cat input.csv | awk -F, '$1~/'"$1"'/ {print "is good"}'
```

You need to close the `'` string, insert the shell `$1` (inside `"` in case there are special characters), then reopen the `'` string.

And you may want to check whether the `$1` from shell contains `/` characters which will 
upset the regular expression.

And as @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams indicated, you don't need to pipe the output of `cat` to awk, you can just get `awk` to read the file directly. That is:

```
cat input.csv | awk ...
```

can be simplified to:

```
awk ... < input.csv
```

Comment: That doesn't actually tell awk to read the file. It tells the shell to feed it directly into awk's stdin instead of using cat.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: I know but I didn't want to get into too much complication.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams The redirection does not "feed it directly into awk's stdin".  The file *becomes* awk's stdin.  The useless use of cat feeds the content of the file to awk's stdin, and that useless I/O is why UUOC is inefficient.

Answer (score 5):

A variable is fine too.

```
awk -F, -v needle="$1" '$1 ~ needle {print "is good"}' < input.csv
```

Comment: Good idea about the extra variable. I guess that eliminates any problem where `$1` may contain special characters, does it?

Comment: Every character is special in its own way.

Answer (score 0):

cat or a redirection isn't needed. Here is a third variant using backslash:

```
awk -F, "\$1~/$1/ {print \"is good\"}" input.csv
```